# react-native TouchableNativeFeedback onPress not working

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, touchableopacity, touchablewithoutfeedback

I have created a composed component to compose TouchableNativeFeedback to wrapperComponent.

```
export default function withFeedback2(
    WrappedComponent
) {
    return class extends BaseComponent {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <View>
                    <TouchableNativeFeedback
                        onPress={() => this.props.onContainerViewPress()}

                    >
                        <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
                    </TouchableNativeFeedback>
                    {/* <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={this.props.onContainerViewPress ? () => this.props.onContainerViewPress() : null}

 >
                        <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
                    </TouchableOpacity> */}
                </View>
            );
        }
    };
}
```

But **OnPress** event of TochableNativeFeedback is not firing. Whereas OnPress event is fired correctly and **onContainerViewPress** prop of wrappercomponent is called if wrappercomponent wrapped under TouchableOpacity.

I am testing this on the Android Platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've discovered that adding a Ripple effect to the `TouchableNativeFeedback` fixes the issue for me:

```
background={TouchableNativeFeedback.Ripple("#FFFFFF",true)}
```

i.e.

```
export default function withFeedback2(
  WrappedComponent
) {
  return class extends BaseComponent {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <View>
          <TouchableNativeFeedback
            onPress={() => this.props.onContainerViewPress()}
            background={TouchableNativeFeedback.Ripple("#FFFFFF",true)}
          >
            <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
          </TouchableNativeFeedback>
        </View>
      );
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Use a `<View></View>` to wrap your `WrappedComponent` for `TouchableNativeFeedback`.

```
<TouchableNativeFeedback
  onPress={() => this.props.onContainerViewPress()}>
    <View>
      <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
    </View>
</TouchableNativeFeedback>
```

Comment: I had a similar problem. I did what you suggested and wrapped my component inside a view, which was wrapped by the TouchableNativeFeedback. I didn't get the ripple effect but the onPress fired. Can you tell me why this is the case?

Answer (score 6):

There are two different `TouchableNativeFeedback` classes. Make sure you import the correct one:

```
import { TouchableNativeFeedback } from "react-native"
import { TouchableNativeFeedback } from "react-native-gesture-handler"
```

I had a similar problem and finally used it from "react-native" library. Importing it from "react-native-gesture-handler" did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try: useForeground={true}

`<TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={() => {}} useForeground={true}>`

Answer (score 0):

You can call method as below:

```
export default function withFeedback2(
    WrappedComponent
) {
    return class extends BaseComponent {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.onContainerViewPress = this.onContainerViewPress.bind(this);

        }
          onContainerViewPress() {
        const { onContainerViewPress } = this.props;
        onContainerViewPress();
    }

        render() {
            return (
                <View>
                    <TouchableNativeFeedback
                                    onPress={() => { this.onContainerViewPress(); }}
                    >
                        <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
                    </TouchableNativeFeedback>
                    {/* <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={this.props.onContainerViewPress ? () => this.props.onContainerViewPress() : null}

 >
                        <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
                    </TouchableOpacity> */}
                </View>
            );
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to import Touchable native feedback from react native gesture handler library

Answer (score 0):

```
import { TouchableNativeFeedback } from "react-native"
import { TouchableNativeFeedback } from "react-native-gesture-handler"
```

Supplementing the answer of [mangei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1735561/mangei) the problem could be if you import it from the wrong place. You have to import it from `react-native-gesture-handler` if you are inside a gesture handler (NOTE: `react-navigation`'s `TabBar` itself has a `PanGestureHandler` in it by default). What `react-native-gesture-handler` does is it wraps components like `ScrollView` or `TouchableNativeFeedback` with its own implementation to be able to handle gestures inside the `GestureHandler` as well that are "not meant" for the `GestureHandler` but rather for the `ScrollView` or the `TouchableNativeFeedback`. If you're inside the gesture handler, you have to import it from `react-native-gesture-handler` else from `react-native`.